# Using paramiko and odoo 9

Tags: python, ssh, orm, paramiko, odoo-9

I'm developing a module that uploads specific files via ssh to specific server based on customer creation:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        if vals:
            testfile=open("/tmp/diegotexting.txt", "w")
            testfile.write("Hi, testing odoo 9 ")
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient() 
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect("foo.org", username="foo", password="foo")
            sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
            sftp.put("/tmp/diegotexting.txt", "/tmp/diegotexting.txt")
            sftp.close()
            ssh.close()
        return super(ResPartner, self).create(vals)
```

It does upload the file in server "foo.org", the problem is that when I open it, it's blank.

I have tested the upload script outside of odoo enviroment and works well(it doesn't show a blank file).

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out; I just needed to close the file before SSH connection.